# Python differentiate data type

Tags: python, types

I have 2 different kind of list in python:

1. test1 = ['abc', 'cde', 'fgh']

2. test2 = [{'name': 'me', 'address': 'usa'}]

Both appear to be a list when i check the type:

`if test1 is list: --> true`

`if test2 is list: --> true`

is there any way i can check if it is a list of string or list of dictionary?

Comment: test2 is not a valid syntax, did you want to use { }?

Comment: hi, thanks for your prompt response. i just updated test2

Comment: What about `type(test1[0])`?

Comment: `isinstance(test2[0], dict) `

Comment: Since lists can be heterogenous, you would have to check the type of *every* element to be sure of the "type".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are both lists, period; type doesn't take into consideration what is *in* the list.

You can use type *hints* to restrict what *should* be in the list, but these only serve to document the intended use, or by tools like `mypy`; they don't affect what you can actually put in the list.

```
from typing import List, Dict


test1: List[str] = ['abc', 'cde', 'fgh']
test2: List[Dict[str,str]] = [{'name': 'me', 'address': 'use']

def foo(x: List[str]):
    ...
```

`mypy` will flag as an error any attempt to pass `test1` to `foo`, but that's allowed when you actually run the code.

`mypy` would also flag as an error something like

```
test3: List[str] = ['foo', 1]
```

since `1` is not a `str`, but again, at runtime that is perfectly legal.

Answer (score 0):

To check if an object is of a class you usually use `isinstance`

```
>>> isinstance("hello", str)
True
>>> isinstance({}, dict)
True
>>> isinstance([], list)
True
>>> isinstance(5, int)
True
>>> isinstance("hello", int)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet:

```
for item in test1:
   print(type(item))
```

Similar snippet for test2.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `test1` and `test2` *are* lists, which you can check via

```
>>> isinstance(test1, list)                                                     
True
>>> isinstance(test2, list)                                                     
True
```

(`test1 is list` and `test2 is list` actually return `False`, because neither are the builtin `list` *class*.)

What might be confusing you is that `test2` is a list with only one element, and that element is a dictionary.

```
>>> test2[0]                                                                    
{'name': 'me', 'address': 'usa'}
>>> type(test2[0])                                                              
dict
```

If you want to know all the types a list holds, you can do

```
>>> l = [1, '2', []]                                                            
>>> set(map(type, l))                                                           
{int, list, str}
# alternative
>>> set(type(x) for x in l)                                                     
{int, list, str}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following:

```py
test1 = ["abc", "cde", "fgh"]
if type(test1) is list:
  print("Hello")
# Hello
```

What it will do is use the `type(arg)` function where you can pass a variable or data directly to get the type as an output.

For example `type("test")` will make it return `<type 'str'>` which means it's a string.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the first element of each list to determine what kind of list it is. For example:

list1_type = typeof(list1[0])

list2_type = typeof(list2[0])

Of course, a list doesn't have to have all the same type, so without checking every element, you can't know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

There are mainly two ways to do this, either with type() or with isinstance(). In case you don't know the exact type of list you have it is preferred to use the former (type()) otherwise the latter is more suitable. 
My solution addresses the first case and it assumes that the list may contain more than one types.

```
test1 = ['abc', 'cde', 'fgh']
test2 = [{'name': 'me', 'address': 'usa'}]
test3 = ['abc', 'cde', 3, [2, 1]]
print("Test1 is a list of ", set([type(elem) for elem in test1])) #str
print("Test2 is a list of ", set([type(elem) for elem in test2])) #dict
print("Test3 is a list of ", set([type(elem) for elem in test3])) #str, int, list
```

I hope this answers your question :-)